# Centering text and buttons under images

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center the text underneath each image and underneath each image I want the button to be centered. I've been using paddings and margins to try to fix my problem but it's not working. Also, am I using the button and figcaption tags correctly?

```css
    figure img {
      border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
      height: 30%;
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 16px 0 0;
    }

    figure figcaption {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }

    figcaption {
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 30px 110px 30px 60px;
    }

    figure button {
      background-color: #a8eb6c;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 110px 30px 60px;
    }
```

```html
<figure>
            <img src="img/drawstring-bag.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
            <img src="img/charm-necklace.jpg" alt="icecream-necklace">
            <img src="img/phone-case.jpg" alt="phone-case">
              <figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption>
              <figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption>
              <figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption>
              <button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button>
              <button role="button">Creative Charms</button>
              <button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button>
          </figure>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: can you share image, what you exactly want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close originally, but you need to make each "card" have it's own container. Therefore, you would want 3 `figure` tags, with each one containing an `img`, a `figcaption`, and a `button`. You could just as easily use `div` tags to accomplish this, but `figure` and `figcaption` give you semantic code. You could always put this group of `figures` inside of a `div` container later on, depending on how you are using it.

```css
figure {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

img {
    max-width: 100px;
    border: 10px solid #a8eb6c
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://www.totallypromotional.com/media/totallypromotional/images/items/TDB100/product/jpg/Polypropylene-Drawstring-Bag-TDB100-red.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
    <figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption>
    <button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-zt9cwiz411/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/2076/5316/avalon_personalized_charm_necklace__39075.1508947216.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on" alt="icecream-necklace">
    <figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption>
    <button role="button">Creative Charms</button>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="https://dimg.dillards.com/is/image/DillardsZoom/zoom/kate-spade-new-york-glitter-ombre-dot-iphone-case/05482185_zi_pink_multicolor.jpg" alt="phone-case">
    <figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption>
    <button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! The only thing now is that all the images are side by side without any space in between. Margin does not seem to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content that you would like aligned. I've wrapped them in `<div>`'s and applied `text-align:center` the the `<div>`'s.

```css
.centerContent {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

figure .centerContent {
  width: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure div img {
  border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

figcaption {
}

figure div button {
  background-color: #a8eb6c;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerContent">
  <figure>
    <div class="centerContent">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
      <figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption>
      <button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button>
    </div>
    <div class="centerContent">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
      <figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption>
      <button role="button">Creative Charms</button>
    </div>
    <div class="centerContent">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag">
      <figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption>
      <button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Also, I would like to recomend that you take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/). You may find it helpful.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps! I have used flex and wrapped a div around each element

```css
    figure img {
      border: 10px solid #a8eb6c;
      height: 30%;
      width: 30%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 16px 0 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    figure figcaption {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    figcaption {
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 30px 110px 30px 60px;
    }

    figure button {
      background-color: #a8eb6c;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 110px 30px 60px;
    }
    .container{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-content: center;
    }
    .center{
     text-align: center;
    }
    .main_container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
     align-content: center;
     }
```

```html
<figure>
     <div class="main_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center"><img src="img/drawstring-bag.jpg" alt="drawstring-bag"></div>
              <div class="center"><figcaption>Purses • Tops • Skirts</figcaption></div>
              <div class="center"><button role="button">Sensational Sewing</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center"><img src="img/charm-necklace.jpg" alt="icecream-necklace"></div>
              <div class="center"><figcaption>Earrings • Pendants • Clay Necklaces</figcaption></div>
              <div class="center"><button role="button">Creative Charms</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center"><img src="img/phone-case.jpg" alt="phone-case"></div>
              <div class="center"><figcaption>Scarves • Mittens • Plushies</figcaption></div>
              <div class="center"><button role="button">Knockout Knitting</button></div>
        </div>

      </div>
</figure>
</main>
```